# mypy error: Callable has no attribute "__get__"

Tags: python, mypy, callable, python-descriptors

I have something like the following:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Callable, Generic, Type, Union, Optional

T = TypeVar("T")
V = TypeVar("V")

class DescClass(Generic[T, V]):
    """A descriptor."""
    def __init__(self, func: Callable[[T], V]) -> None:
        self.func = func

    def __get__(self, instance: Optional[T], owner: Type[T]) -> Callable[[], V]:
        return self.func.__get__(instance, owner)

class C:
    @DescClass
    def f(self): ...
```

...for which Mypy will return this error:

```
test.py:12: error: "Callable[[T], Any]" has no attribute "__get__"
```

What is the canonical way to specify the type for `func`, so that Mypy understands it is a descriptor ([and thus always has a `__get__`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods))?

Update: it's a bit humorous that "descriptor" [has no hits](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search.html?q=descriptor) when searching the Mypy help.

Comment: Related, but [not the same Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54413434/type-hinting-with-descriptors).

Comment: Well, `Callable` in general does *not* have a `__get__`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga right. `class MyCallable: def __call__(self): ...` etc etc. so....

Comment: But why would you need to hint this? Every function is a non-data descriptor.

Comment: @FilipDimitrovski Yes, but functions aren't the only callables that exist in python. So the type hint has to specify "something that can be called *and* is a descriptor".

Comment: Perhaps a good use-case for [protocols/structural types](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/protocols.html)

Comment: @FilipDimitrovski because future (read: stupid, forgetful, careless....) me may try to monkey patch using a functional syntax, and some callable non-function object: `C.g = DescClass(callable_obj)` and it will not work.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga last i heard the protocol thing was still in development hell. but that's probably teh answer. a protocol-like type `Descriptor`- a sub type of `Callable` which adds on the desc protocol requirements.

Comment: @RickTeachey I had to abandon my own attemp to incorporate a protocol, although it was rather complex (requiring classmethds etc) and I'm not sure the protocol was the source of the problems exactly. I ended up just going with an `abc.ABC` . Read the answer/comments in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53126193/classmethods-in-generic-protocols-with-self-types-mypy-type-checking-failure). Your use-case may be simple enough that it "just works", but it's definitely not a feature ready for production, at least that was my impression.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that looks really helpful- thanks!

Comment: It's possible to *define* the type of a descriptor as ``class Descriptor(Protocol[T, V]): def __get__(self, instance: Optional[T], owner: Optional[Type[T]]) -> V: pass`` (add ``__set__``/``__del__`` if a data descriptor is desired). This then works correctly when ``DescClass`` is set to take a ``func: Descriptor[T, Callable[[], V]]``. However, as of MyPy 0.812 the ultimate problem is that the ``def`` "creates" just a ``Callable[[C], Any]"`` without any information that it is a descriptor as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to work fine on modern Python and modern mypy:

```py
from typing import (
    TypeVar,
    Callable,
    Generic, 
    Type, 
    Optional,
    cast,
    Protocol
)

T_contra = TypeVar("T_contra", contravariant=True)
V = TypeVar("V")
P_co = TypeVar("P_co", covariant=True)


class DescriptorProto(Protocol[P_co, T_contra]):
    def __get__(
        self, 
        instance: Optional[T_contra], 
        owner: Type[T_contra]
    ) -> P_co:
        ...


FuncType = DescriptorProto[Callable[[], V], T_contra]


class DescClass(Generic[T_contra, V]):
    """A descriptor."""

    def __init__(self, func: Callable[[T_contra], V]) -> None:
        self.func = cast(FuncType[V, T_contra], func)

    def __get__(
        self, 
        instance: Optional[T_contra], 
        owner: Type[T_contra]
    ) -> Callable[[], V]:
        return self.func.__get__(instance, owner)


class C:
    @DescClass
    def f(self) -> None: ...
```

Comment: NICE! I guess this has been fixed (I haven't tested your code but it looks fine to me!).